# Excel runs VBA code fine for several files and then stops in with the run-time error 91

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to use Excel VBA code to make a change to all workbooks in a specific directory by locating a specific phrase in each workbook, and then deleting all rows (including the row of where the phrase is found), and the saving each file.

The problem I’m having is that this code runs fine for a couple of files, and then suddenly it stops in the middle of processing with the run-time error ‘91’ (“Object variable or With block variable not set”).  So some files get processed without any issue, and then suddenly the code stops with the error.  I tested this a couple of times to see if the number of files processed is consistent and unfortunately it's not (221/440 the first time, then 82/440 the second time, etc.)

I’m not sure why this is as I'm fairly new to Excel VBA and am trying to figure out this issue with the right solution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub ChangeFiles()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim dirName As String
Dim wks As Worksheet

dirName = "F:\Documents\” 

MyPath = dirName & "*.xls"
MyFile = Dir(MyPath)
If MyFile > "" Then MyFile = dirName & MyFile

Do While MyFile <> ""
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then Exit Do

    Workbooks.Open MyFile

    With ActiveWorkbook
        For Each wks In .Worksheets
                Cells.Find(What:="<End of Traveller>", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
                xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
                xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
                Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
        Next
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    MyFile = Dir
    If MyFile > "" Then MyFile = dirName & MyFile
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: if the find does not find `"<End of Traveller>"` then it returns `Nothing` and you cannot activate `Nothing`.  You need to test that the find returned a viable range before trying to activate.

Comment: Another note - don't rely on `ActiveWorkbook`. `Workbooks.Open` returns a workbook object that you can use: `Dim wb as Workbook`, then `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)`.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to open 440 Workbooks, that is time consuming, and probably after some loops, VBA *gets tired*. I guess those 440 workbooks are not exactly the same, so you need to *pause* your code and make sure the workbook has been opened correctly. Try adding `DoEvents` after `Workbooks.Open MyFile` and also after `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True`. Also, check what @ScottCraner and @BigBen said in their comments, because they are right.